# If a set S is linearly independent with each element having norm 1, is S orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space.

If a set $S \subset V $ is linearly independent and each member of $S$ has norm 1, is $S$ orthonormal?

I know that if you remove the norm condition, it is not true that $S$ is an orthogonal set.

Comment: If $S$ was a set of linearly independent vectors, without the norm condition, and you know that it’s not necessarily true that it’s an orthogonal set, then dividing each vector by its length won’t effect the linear independence or angles between the vectors.

Answer (score 5):

No. In $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual Euclidean metric, for example, consider
$$
S = \bigg\{ (0,1), \bigg( \frac35,\frac45 \bigg) \bigg\}.
$$